# Can old App_Web.xxxx.dlls affect site behavior?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I have ASP.NET Web Site project that deploys as precompiled to server. After deploy bin folder contains multiple App_Web.xxx.dll files. I know that I can delete old files before deploying new version but if I don't, can these old files somehow affect web site behavior? How ASP.NET finds that my last version page had compiled to App_Web_aaaaa.dll and App_Web_bbbbb.dll contains old version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes it can, as you may wind up with namespace conflicts/multiple declarations that are the same.  It's just safer to delete the old ones prior to deploying the new ones.

Comment: And when I recompile project how ASP.NET finds needed App_Web.xxxx.dll? For example, I create web site with default page, deploy it, totally change that page, redeploy it without deleting old one and ASP.NET always show proper page. Link to brief explanation will be very appreciated.