# XCOPY - delete contents of folder first

Tags: vb.net, xcopy

I deploy an ASP.NET app using XCOPY.  It is a website rather than a web app.

I have noticed that there are over one hundred DLLs in the bin folder on the server e.g. app_web_ln122.dll, app_web_ln132.dll, app_web_gh5634.dll etc.  I believe these dlls contain classes from the website at different points in time (they still exist because I have not manually deleted them).  Is this correct?

Is there a DOS command/xcopy parameter to delete the contents of the folder before XCOPY copies the files accross.  I have Googled this and I have spent an hour investigating.  The commands I have tried have not work.

Comment: Uh, why don't you just delete the files before XCopying?  There's a DOS command that can do that.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_MS-DOS_commands#DEL_or_ERASE

Comment: @Robert Harvey, thanks.  Can you use the DEL command with networked paths e.g. del \\computername\c$\Test? I would test this myself but I don't have access to another networked PC at the moment.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is a risk leaving these DLLs lying around? I didn't think there was, but this question seems to suggest there is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644965/can-old-app-web-xxxx-dlls-affect-site-behavior

Comment: The risk probably outweighs their usefulness.  Make a backup first before deleting any of them.

Comment: Why would I need to make a backup if they are old files? Thanks again.

Comment: You have been warned. :)

Comment: Thanks. If I delete the entire contents of the folder and then republish the app then I assume that there is no risk? Can you post an answer so that I can give credit as there are some good comments above?

Comment: Robocopy is an advanced alternative which I've used to do just that. It can delete unwanted files using a compare folder function. Or mirroring.